# Fill many2many field from other many2many field

Tags: python, postgresql, onchange, odoo

In product.template model, I have a one2many field(attribute_line_ids) making reference the following class:

```
class product_attribute_line(osv.osv):
_name = "product.attribute.line"
_rec_name = 'attribute_id'
_columns = {
    'product_tmpl_id': fields.many2one('product.template', 'Product Template', required=True, ondelete='cascade'),
    'attribute_id': fields.many2one('product.attribute', 'Attribute', required=True, ondelete='restrict'),
    'value_ids': fields.many2many('product.attribute.value', id1='line_id', id2='val_id', string='Product Attribute Value'),
}
```

On the other hand, in product.template created a many2one field making reference to a new model(comun.denominador):

```
'cm_id' : fields.many2one('comun.denominador','Comun denominador', select=True, ondelete='cascade')
```

So that when I select 'cm_id' it brings records to product.template from comun.denominador by means of on_change function.

This is my onchange_function:

```
def on_change_cm_id(self,cr, uid, ids,cm_id,context=None):
    context=context or {}
    attributes_product_template = []
    value = {}
    if ids:
        old_note_ids = self.pool.get('product.attribute.line').search(cr, uid,[('product_tmpl_id','in',ids)])
        self.pool.get('product.attribute.line').unlink(cr, uid, old_note_ids)
    attribute_cm_ids = []
    attribute_cm_ids = self.pool.get('attribute.comun.denominador.line').search(cr, uid, [('comun_denominador_id', '=', cm_id)])
    for attribute_id in self.pool.get('attribute.comun.denominador.line').read(cr, uid, attribute_cm_ids, ['attribute_comun_denominador_id', 'value_comun_denominador_ids']):
        attributes_product_template.append((0,0,{'value_ids':attribute_id['value_comun_denominador_ids'][0],'attribute_id':attribute_id['attribute_comun_denominador_id'][0]}))
    value.update(attribute_line_ids=attributes_product_template)
    return {'value':value}
```

These models store information in comun.denominador:

```
class product_attribute_line(osv.osv):
_name = "attribute.comun.denominador.line"
_rec_name = 'attribute_comun_denominador_id'
_columns = {
    'comun_denominador_id': fields.many2one('comun.denominador', 'Comun denominador', required=True, ondelete='cascade'),
    'attribute_comun_denominador_id': fields.many2one('product.attribute', 'Attribute', required=True, ondelete='restrict', readonly=True),
    'value_comun_denominador_ids': fields.many2many('product.attribute.value', id1='line_id', id2='val_id', string='Product Attribute Value'),
}

class comun_denominador(osv.osv):
_name='comun.denominador'
_rec_name='comun_denominador'
_columns = {
    'comun_denominador': fields.char('Común denominador', size=10),
    'code': fields.char('Código clasificación', size=10),
    'attribute_line_comun_denominador_ids' : fields.one2many('attribute.comun.denominador.line', 'comun_denominador_id', 'Atributos del comun denominador')             
    }
```

As you can see in my onchange_function all I want to do is to populate fields
   'attribute_id'
and
   'value_ids'
from 'product.attribute.line' model with the values  'attribute_comun_denominador_id' and 'value_comun_denominador_ids' belonging to 'attribute.comun.denominador.line' model.

Onchange function works great with fields many2one ('attribute_comun_denominador_id'->'attribute_id'), but in the case of many2many fields ('value_comun_denominador_ids'->'value_ids'), I get this error:

```
File "/home/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 1568, in convert_to_cache
    raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %s" % (self, value))
    ValueError: Wrong value for product.attribute.line.value_ids: 1
```

Does anyone know how to do migration correctly between many2many fields?

Answer (score 0):

```
def on_change_cm_id(self,cr, uid, ids,cm_id,context=None):
    context=context or {}
    attributes_product_template = []
    value = {}
    if ids:
        old_note_ids = self.pool.get('product.attribute.line').search(cr, uid,[('product_tmpl_id','in',ids)])
        self.pool.get('product.attribute.line').unlink(cr, uid, old_note_ids)
    attribute_cm_ids = []
    attribute_cm_ids = self.pool.get('attribute.comun.denominador.line').search(cr, uid, [('comun_denominador_id', '=', cm_id)])
    for attribute_id in self.pool.get('attribute.comun.denominador.line').read(cr, uid, attribute_cm_ids, ['attribute_comun_denominador_id', 'value_comun_denominador_ids']):
        attributes_product_template.append((0,0,{'value_ids':[(6,0,[attribute_id['value_comun_denominador_ids'][0]])],'attribute_id':attribute_id['attribute_comun_denominador_id'][0]}))
    value.update(attribute_line_ids=attributes_product_template)
    return {'value':value}
```